# Paypal plus integration with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-plus

I have integrated the paypal plus using (Germany) sandbox account. I have also setup the payment wall using (https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js).

I have genreated the token using direct CURL (https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token). It's working fine already

Payment wall look like this : http://prntscr.com/hupq6b
When i choose  paypal options it's work fine but when i select the "Credit card" & "Direct Debit" options its redirect to appropriate form but after submit the paypal form nothing returns.

Would you please give me the solution for the above problem. Is there any settings do in paypal account ?

Thanks,
Dhaval

Comment: Are you still facing the issue? Ideally, after submitting the form it should approve the card and return back to the return url provided.

Answer (score -2):

PayPal Payment Gateway Integration in CodeIgniter

please visit: https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter

```
               OR
```

https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-codeigniter/

Comment: I need to implement PayPal plus payment not the simple PayPal. And i already implemented but issue with "credit card" and "direct debit" this both option when i select for payment then redirect to appropraite form but after submit the form not response the status. I used this plugins in magento also but same issue in magento also.